# splitting the string and choosing the middle part containing two set of parenthesis

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

As I know for selecting a part of a string we use `split`. For example, if `node1.Text` is `test (delete) if we choose delete`

```
string b1 = node1.Text.Split('(')[0];
```

then that means we have chosen `test`, But if I want to choose `delete` from `node1.Text` how can I do?

**Update:**

Another question is that when there are two sets of parenthesis in the string, how one could aim at `delete`?. For example is string is `test(2) (delete) - if we choose delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use regex, and then just remove the parentheses:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(yourString, @"\((.*?)\)").Value.
               Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
```

Or better:

```
Regex.Match(yourString, @"\((.*?)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

If you want to extract multiple strings in parentheses:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string>();
var result = Regex.Matches(yourString, @"\((.*?)\)");
foreach(Match x in result)
      matches.Add(x.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Why not `Regex.Match(yourString, @"\((.*?)\)").Groups[1].Value`, then you don't need to remove parentheses?

Comment: @juharr You're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But if we have two parentheses?

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would choose your answer as accepted, but it is already marked as Duplicate(!!??)

Answer (score 0):

If your string is *always* `xxx(yyy)zzz` format, you can add `)` character so split it and get the second item like;

```
var s = "test (delete) if we choose delete";
string b1 = s.Split(new[] { '(', ')' })[1];
```

Comment: Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tmp = node1.Text.Split('(')[1];
string final = tmp.Split(')')[0];
```

Is also possible.

With the index `[x]` you target the part of the string before and after the character you have split the original string at. If the character occurs multiple times, your resulting string hat more parts.